# How to set up YCM to support linux kernel development?

Tags: vim, linux-kernel, youcompleteme

I tried YCM(you complete me) several days, it works pretty good under a normal C/C++ development environment. After I tried it with Linux source tree, however, many features are paralyzed including `GoToDeclaration` and `autocomplete`.

How can I set up a kernel development environment with YCM?

Comment: Kernel is pretty big project. Regular approaches may not work well here. I tried OmniCompletion (the part of vim) and it also hangs the system when trying to autocomplete something. The only thing works well for me here is `cscope` (with `cscope_maps.vim` plugin). Also Eclipse works pretty well, if you are into GUI stuff. But I actually haven't heard of someone successfully using autocompletion for kernel development.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Well, It seems that a lot of kernel hackers prefer emacs.

Comment: Emacs? Not vim? Are you sure? :) I'm not implying anything, just haven't seen one yet. And what do they use to navigate code and for autocompletion?

Comment: @SamProtsenko, I just guessing... due to that I googled a lot and found nothing about how to set up vim for kernel development...

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa! It's a lot on this topic out there, really. A vast majority of kernel developers using vim, as per my observations. I can provide some information as an answer, if you are interested exactly in Vim configuration for kernel development.

Comment: Please forgive my  ignorance. If you have any experience about it, Please show me some information.. :)

Comment: Have you tried running ctags with the `-n` argument? That should decrease the size of the tags file and the time it takes to process it.

Comment: @DouglasSu Please create another question, like "vim configuration for Linux kernel development", as it would be inappropriate to put this sort of information as answer to this question

Comment: @SamProtsenko http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676829/vim-configuration-for-linux-kernel-development, Thx. :)