# editing kernel files with 'eclipse' - almost one WHOLE DAY to index

Tags: eclipse, linux-kernel

I have followed [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source) guide to set eclipse for editing the kernel (I have the latest **Mars** release of eclipse ).

I have intel duo t9600 and Im running eclipse via Vmware workstation.
 Its been almost  a whole day since it started indexing and still havent done (62%)
 Is that suppose to be like that ??

Comment: As it stated in item #42 (by your link): `On a platter drive indexing will take upwards of 20 minutes to complete, on a SSD indexing will take about 5 minutes to complete`. It sounds about right, so it shouldn't take the whole day. Make sure that you are indexing only files that you are interested in (exclude architectures other than yours, etc): see items #24 and #32. Also it would be more wise to do it on native Linux platform, not on some virtual machine (it may be exactly the explanation why it takes so much time). If you want better speed -- I can propose you to use `cscope` + `vim`.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Thanks! can you refer me to a guide how to use cscope+vim with kernel source tree ? is http://cscope.sourceforge.net/large_projects.html any good?

Comment: I have answered recently similar question (about vim + cscope configuration). The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676829/vim-configuration-for-linux-kernel-development/33682137#33682137). You can use it as a guide. Using `find` commands I provided there you should be able to index further (with `cscope`) your kernel sources pretty fast. Takes about 1 minute for me.