# plugin to vim that shows definition of function/macro/struct in a popup box?

Tags: vim, plugins, code-completion

Im using **vim** with **ctag+tagbar** plugin to navigate through kernel code and its amazing ! Thanks to a guide I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676829/vim-configuration-for-linux-kernel-development/33682137#33682137).

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks) about some nice shortcuts for ctags that helps a lot, but I couldnt find a way that a definition(of structs/function etc) would show in popup box - something like **eclipse ide**.

Is there a way to do so with ctag? is there a **plug-in** I can add to vim that would that ? so when the mouse cursor(or also keyboard cursor) on function a popup box next to it will show?

Thanks!

Comment: i’m trying to figure this out [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42179/how-to-load-method-definition-in-a-popup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should avoid trying to use Vim as an IDE.  It's meant to be a modular text editor.

Having said that, if you are looking for eclipse functionality inside of Vim, you may want to consider [eclim](http://eclim.org).  Another good set of plugins are the Clang based tools, like [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) and [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe).

Answer (score 0):

ctags is very useful plugin, but if you also use ctags you can then copy file http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim to your ~/.vim/plugin directory and this will add keymappings that will allow you to jump to definition or show it in horizontal or vertical split.

I also added to my cscope_maps file an extra set of mappings like so:

```
nmap <C-h>g :tab cs find g <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
```

to open my search in a new tab.

Example above allows you to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> and then <kbd>g</kbd> to "find global definition(s) of the token under cursor" and open it in a new tab.

Consider using cscope- it can also work with ctags (I always use both).

I know that this is not a pop-up window, but vim is not an IDE.