# linux kernel make tag variable

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Linux kernel source can use `make tags` to get the tag for editor.
In [scripts/tags.sh](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/tags.sh#L7), line7 and line8 say that "Uses the following environment variables: `ARCH`, `SUBARCH`, `SRCARCH`, `srctree`, `src`, `obj`"
I want to ask What are these variable meaning?

I already read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676829/vim-configuration-for-linux-kernel-development),but it just mention the two vairables, `SRCARCH` and `SUBARCH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Variables you should use

Next variables can be passed to `tags.sh` (actually you should pass them to `make tags cscope` command, and Makefile will pass them to `tags.sh` for you).

1. `ARCH`: which architecture to index. You can see all architectures list just by doing `ls -l arch/` in your kernel source tree.
2. `SUBARCH`: the meaning of this variable depends on your architecture:

   - if `ARCH=arm`, `SUBARCH` will be used to determine `arch/arm/mach-*` and `arch/arm/plat-*` directories, and these directories will be indexed
   - if `ARCH=um`, use `SUBARCH` to specify which architecture you actually want to use in your User-Mode Linux (like `SUBARCH=arm` or `SUBARCH=x86`)
   - for the rest of architectures, you can omit this variable
3. `ALLSOURCE_ARCHS`: use this to index more than one architecture. Like `ALLSOURCE_ARCHS="x86 mips arm"` or `ALLSOURCE_ARCHS="all"`. If you only want to index one architecture, omit this variable and use `ARCH` instead.
4. `COMPILED_SOURCE`: set this variable to 1 if you want to index only actually compiled source files. If you want to index all source files, omit setting this variable.
5. `O=` (this is actually Makefile parameter): use absolute paths (useful if you want to load created cscope/ctags index files outside of kernel directory, e.g. for development of out-of-tree kernel modules). If you want to use relative paths (i.e. you're gonna do development only in kernel dir), just omit that parameter.

### Variables you don't need to touch

1. `SRCARCH`: being set from `ARCH` variable in Makefile and then passed to script. You probably don't need to mess with it, just set `ARCH` variable correctly
2. `srctree`: kernel source tree path. This variable will be passed from Makefile automatically if you're using this script via `make cscope tags`.
3. `src` and `obj` variables: those are not used by `scripts/tags.sh` anymore. It was replaced by utilizing `KBUILD_SRC` variable, which is provided from Makefile automatically, when you provide `O=...` parameter to it.

### Usage

Basically, I'd recommend to only use `scripts/tags.sh` via `make` invocation. Example:

```
$ make O=. ARCH=arm SUBARCH=omap2 COMPILED_SOURCE=1 cscope tags
```

or

```
$ make ARCH=x86 cscope tags
```

Comment: No offense. Does official website give these information? I want to know the reference link. If I have another question about it, i can read doc first. Thanks.

Comment: @amikai The meaning of those variables for `tags.sh` is not documented, so I just went through script itself and related `git log` messages, and figured the usage. All those variables (apart from `COMPILED_SOURCE`) are actually kernel build system variables, so you can read about most of them in [Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.txt](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.txt), but it won't make much sense with respect to `tags.sh`.